# storing and importing local data in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to store data for select lists in my react app:

I have a js file:

```
export default {
    views: [
        {
            month: 1,
            year: 0,
            day: 2
        }
    ]
};
```

How can I import this into my react component so I can use it for lookups?

`import views from '../config/views.js';`

Something like this:

```
  onChange(e) {

  this.props.actions.navigate(views[e]);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can simply use a JSON array file which you can import in your react application and just do whatever you want to.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that you are exporting an object with a views property on it, to access it you would need to do: views.views[e].

If you want to see what's going on just: console.log(views).